In JUnit, is there a way to include a union of test classes and tags?
I'm using JUnit with Gradle.
I want to include a set of Test Classes I know and a set of tags I know.
When I use TestFilter.includeTestsMatching() with jUnitPlatformOptions.includeTags() the result is the intersection of the 2.
It's the same when I use Test.include() with jUnitPlatformOptions.includeTags().
What I want is the union. Is there a way to do this? Appreciate some clues.
